# jquery, django-deleteview: delete table row records

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to open up a twitter bootstrap model for the confirmation of deleting the records while constructing a simple CRUD application.

this is where the confirmation message appears in a bootstrap modal form with delete button at the end to let us delete the selected row.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myDeleteModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myEditModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only"></span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myDeleteModalLabel"></h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Are you sure you want to delete {{ obj.name }}?</p>
                <form action="" method="post" id="delete_form" id="form-modal-body">

                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button class="btn btn-danger btn-small pull-left" data-dismiss="modal">
                            <i class="icon-remove"></i>Cancel                       
                        </button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="delete_submit">Delete</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

And this is where the records are listed with a delete action at the end of each row:

```
<tbody id="new-day-row">
        {% for day in object_list %}
        <tr class="odd">
            <td id='day-{{day.id}}'>{{ day.name }}</td>
            <td id='workday-{{day.id}}'>{{ day.work_day }}</td>
            <td class="td-actions">
                <a class="red" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myDeleteModal">
                    <i class="icon-trash bigger-130"></i>
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
```

A very simple deleteView:

```
class DayDeleteView(DeleteView):
    model = Day

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('day_home')
```

I was hoping to get an answer to trigger the delete action in jquery. I had so far tried to bind the .remove() function on the click event of the button but was not successfull whatsoever and truly not worth it to post here. I Would be very thankfull for suggestions and answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd just use `on`:

html:

```
<div class="modal-footer" id="{{obj.id}}">
```

jquery:

```
  $('#delete_submit').on('click', function() {
    var id = $('.modal-footer').attr('id');
    $.ajax({
        url: "your/delete/handler",
        type: "POST",
        data: { id : id },
    });
```

Comment: Would you elaborate please. I dont have much knowledge about ajax.